# parents and appendto don't work together?

Tags: jquery, appendto, parents

jquery.parents and jquery.appendTo seem don't work together, for instance, I want to add a new element to the clicked button's parent's element only,

```
   $('.local').click(function(){

    var object = $(this);
    var parent = object.parents('.block').css({background:'yellow'});
    $('<li class="item"></li>').appendTo('.items',parent).html('\
        <p>added</p>\
    ');

    return false;
});
```

html,

```
<!-- block -->
<div class="block">

    <ul class="items"></ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="local">add</a>
    </ul>

</div>
<!-- block -->

<!-- block -->
<div class="block">

    <ul class="items"></ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="local">add</a>
    </ul>

</div>
<!-- block -->


<!-- block -->
<div class="block">

    <ul class="items"></ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="local">add</a>
    </ul>

</div>
<!-- block -->
```

so when I click the first **add button**. the **added paragraph** should be added to the first's **add button**'s parent's element only but not other parents which have the same class name.

Here is the [test page](http://jsfiddle.net/G8Y92/).

Can I fix it? Or I must have coded it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) doesn't work that way. Try this:

```
  $('.local').click(function(){

    var object = $(this);
    var parent = object.parents('.block').css({background:'yellow'});
    $('<li class="item"></li>').appendTo($('.items',parent)).html('\
        <p>added</p>\
    ');

    return false;
});
```

Instead of `.appendTo('.items',parent))`, it should be `.appendTo($('.items',parent))`.

Comment: @MattBradley For posterity, please explain what was needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".local", function(){
    $(this)
        .closest(".block")
        .css("background-color","yellow")
        .find("ul.items")
        .append( $("<li>")
            .attr("class","item")
            .html( $("<p>").html("added") );
        );
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/dbsfy/).

**Please note that `on()` was added in jQuery 1.7.**

We attach the click handler to any element with class `local`. When clicked, it will traverse up the DOM until it finds the closest element with class `block`. It sets it background color to yellow then selects its child `ul` with class `items`. It then appends the new `li` element. Meanwhile, we also set the `li`'s class and text with jQuery.